# Why is clicking on some questions opening up a new tab

Tags: bug

This question [415 Error when posting JSON in Java with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810773/415-error-when-posting-json-in-java-with-jersey) opened up in a new tab everytime I clicked on it from the home page, while the question that lies immediately after or the other 10 that I tried open in the same tab.

What's special about some questions? It seemed like it happened earlier too but I ignored it thinking I might have had the Ctrl pressed. So, happened multiple times and possibly with different question links. Using Chrome on Windows XP. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Nope, don't see that kind of behaviour here at all.

Comment: Still happening. Everytime!

Comment: This is almost certainly a setting in your browser.  I don't have Chrome here, so I can't point you to the correct setting.

Comment: Puzzled! Wonder what that setting could be that's able to treat two question links on the homepage differently.

Comment: If you're still interested, clicking ONLY on the Question link or the posted time has this odd behavior. I can still click on the Votes or Answers or the Views elements and see normal behavior. And, again, it's only this one particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple choices:

- You have a browser extension randomly adding a target=_blank
- You have a virus randomly adding a target=_blank (wut?)
- Your ctrl key is broken. Or half-broken. This seems like the most correct guess.

Comment: You forgot to add that you can't be sure.